# Linking MVC controllers and Actions with Angular 2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, angular2-routing

I really stucked in MVC + Angular 2 project in the first Step. The problem is, **How to connect controllers and actions with Angular 2?** Is there any routing needed?

I have done with all setups with Visual Studio 2015 to work with Angular 2. And it successfully works. But i really doing my projects in ASP.NET MVC 5 (Not ASP.NET Core). Here i dont know how the Controllers and Actions work with Angular. How can i route (navigate) to several controllers and actions in my project.

Since MVC consists of several controllers and actions. There will be many views for several actions and for every action there will be a GET(View) and POST(Form Submit) method also.

If anyone work with **Angular 2 + ASP.NET MVC** let me know how the Controllers and Actions are getting connected.

Comment: Please add more details, this question is very vague. What are you trying to achieve, what have you attempted, and what problems are you having?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are building your first SPA that communicates with a REST API.

For starters, you should get two things straight:

1. The ASP.NET MVC is your REST API. It will expose endpoints that can be requested via HTTP calls.
2. Your Angular 2 is the SPA (Single Page Application), which will make HTTP calls to the REST API you wrote in ASP.NET, and that API will give back responses of whatever you want. You can then use that response data to your liking in your Angular 2 frontend.

That being said, the first step you want to do is make sure you can properly access your API endpoints. Download a tool called [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) and test this with ease.

Ideally, you want to make this API a JSON API, because that will be the easiest thing to work with for your frontend. Plus, it's basically the de facto standard. But as always, use what works best for your use case.

Once your endpoints are working as intended, what you need to do is make some AJAX calls in your frontend that will hit those server endpoints. For Angular 2, you can use the [`Http`](https://angular.io/guide/http) package.

You will undoubtedly come across a CORS (Cross Origin Request Sharing) browser error when making the calls to your server. This is basically the browser refusing to send requests to your server until your server explicitly says you are allowed to make requests to it, assuming you are not on the same host and port.

---

The above was a really brief and limited-detail breakdown of what you need to do. For an example of putting it all together, check out my [Angular 2/Golang chat room app](https://github.com/lansana/ng2-golang-app). As you will see from [this file](https://github.com/lansana/ng2-golang-app/blob/master/main.go), I expose some endpoints to allow create/read/update/delete actions for Todo's in my Go server. And the Angular 2 code is in [this directory](https://github.com/lansana/ng2-golang-app/tree/master/client).

**One last tip:** If you are serving your front end files and exposing your API endpoints all on the same ASP.NET server, as opposed to having one ASP.NET server for the REST API, and one for the serving of UI files, then two things are true:

1. You need to have a catchall route in the server that will serve your `index.html`. You can see an example of this in [this file](https://github.com/lansana/ng2-golang-app/blob/master/main.go). You'll notice a long that starts with `r.NoRoute`...that is where I say "no route was found so far, therefore serve index.html and let the Angular 2 handle the routing from there".
2. You no longer need to worry about CORS errors

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not actually, you will create and Expose APIs (WEB API) in your MVC project and your Angular 2 will consume those APIs.